# Automatically expand all arrays from Invoke-RestMethod and save to CSV in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm using the Invoke-RestMethod to get the data from REST API. The response is an array of strings and hash tables.
I need to save the response into a CSV file. I know that I can use explicit select-object.
This is what I have now:

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $requestHeaders
$response | select-object `
@{Name="HashTable1_Column1"; Expression={ $_.HashTable1.Column1}},
@{Name="HashTable1_Column2"; Expression={ $_.HashTable1.Column2}},
NormalStringColumn1,
NormalStringColumn2,
@{Name="HashTable2_Column1"; Expression={ $_.HashTable2.Column1}},
@{Name="HashTable2_Column2"; Expression={ $_.HashTable2.Column2}}, | Export-Csv $filePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 -Delimiter ";"
```

but is there any way how to expand all hash tables dynamically without the need of typing all fields and save the response with all expanded properties if I don't know the structure of the response?

This is the JSON sample:

```
{
"HistoricalProperties":{
  "PropertyName":"Name",
  "IsProductive":"true",
  "time":"09:00-17:00",
  "Id":"id",
  "Sum":"8.0000"
},
"Date":"2021-01-25T00:00:00",
"Email":"email",
"EmployeeId":"id",
"Number":1,
"ActualProperties":{
  "PropertyName":"Name",
  "IsProductive":"true",
  "time":"09:00-17:00",
  "Id":"id",
  "Sum":"9.0000"
 }
}
```

and this is desired CSV:

```
"HistoricalProperties_PropertyName";"HistoricalProperties_IsProductive";"HistoricalProperties_time";"HistoricalProperties_Id";"HistoricalProperties_Sum";"Date";"Email";"EmployeeId";"EmployeePosKey";"Number";"ActualProperties_PropertyName";"ActualProperties_IsProductive";"ActualProperties_time";"ActualProperties_Id";"ActualProperties_Sum"
"Name";"true";"09:00-17:00";"id";"8.0000";"2021-01-25T00:00:00";"email";"id";"010D570CB5";1;"Name";"true";"09:00-17:00";"id";"8.0000"
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide a simple, representative sample illustrating the structure of the JSON. Note that what [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) returns are (arrays of) `[pscustomobject]` instances, not hashtables.

Comment: @mklement0 thank you for correcting me I'm a PS newbie. When I try the API in the Postman the response is in XML so I think it's the same in PS. But the point is what if I don't know the structure and I want to expand all [pscustomobject]s?

Comment: It'll still help if you provide _sample_ JSON, plus the expected CSV output. Are the some of the array elements really _strings_? If so, what column name would you choose for them in the CSV, ...?

Comment: But PowerShell already talks XML (kind off). Unfortunately there is no good built-in way to display an XML data structure i PowerShell. But `Show-Object` is available in the [PowerShellCookbook](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellCookbook/1.3.6) at PSGallery.

Comment: @soldous, thanks, but please [edit] both into your question, where you can apply [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *reflection* to inspect the `[pscustomobject]` instances returned from your [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) call, using the [intrinsic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) `.psobject` member's `.Properties` collection, which allows you to programmatically examine any object's properties.

Note that the following solution is limited to *one* level of nesting, suitable for handling your sample data. Deeper nesting would require a *recursive* solution (though representing more deeply nested objects in a CSV could get impractical).

```sh
# Simulate an Invoke-RestMethod call
# by parsing a JSON string literal.
$fromJson = ConvertFrom-Json @'
[
  {
    "HistoricalProperties": {
      "PropertyName": "Name",
      "IsProductive": "true",
      "time": "09:00-17:00",
      "Id": "id",
      "Sum": "8.0000"
    },
    "Date": "2021-01-25T00:00:00",
    "Email": "email",
    "EmployeeId": "id",
    "Number": 1,
    "ActualProperties": {
      "PropertyName": "Name",
      "IsProductive": "true",
      "time": "09:00-17:00",
      "Id": "id",
      "Sum": "9.0000"
    }
  }
]
'@

# Loop over all [pscustomobject] instances that the JSON objects
# inside the array were parsed into.
# Note: The assumption is that if there are multiple instances,
#       they all have the same internal structure (properties).
$fromJson | ForEach-Object {
  # Convert the object at hand to a flat representation,
  # using an aux. ordered hashtable.
  $oht = [ordered] @{}
  foreach ($prop in $_.psobject.Properties) {
    if ($prop.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) { # nested object
        foreach ($nestedProp in $prop.Value.psobject.Properties) {
        $oht[($prop.Name + '_' + $nestedProp.Name)] = $nestedProp.Value
      }
    }
    else { # primitive value, such as a string
        $oht[$prop.Name] = $prop.Value
    }
  }
  # Output the hashtable as a [pscustomobject].
  # Note: This [pscustomobject] cast (conversion) is no longer required 
  #       in PowerShell (Core) 7+, where you can output $oht directly.
  [pscustomobject] $oht
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';' # ./o.csv
```

The above outputs the following:

```
"HistoricalProperties_PropertyName";"HistoricalProperties_IsProductive";"HistoricalProperties_time";"HistoricalProperties_Id";"HistoricalProperties_Sum";"Date";"Email";"EmployeeId";"Number";"ActualProperties_PropertyName";"ActualProperties_IsProductive";"ActualProperties_time";"ActualProperties_Id";"ActualProperties_Sum"
"Name";"true";"09:00-17:00";"id";"8.0000";"1/25/2021 12:00:00 AM";"email";"id";"1";"Name";"true";"09:00-17:00";"id";"9.0000"
```

Note:

- To save the CSV to a *file*, use [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) instead of [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv). Be sure to specify an encoding, such as `-Encoding utf8`, because in *Windows PowerShell* the default is ASCII(!)
- In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* the solution can be simplified in two ways:

  - You don't need the `[pscustomobject]` cast before `$oht`, because `ConvertTo-Csv` now also accepts (ordered and unordered) hashtables as input.
  - You don't need the `-NoTypeInformation` switch anymore.

Comment: So we need to explore the structure to get to a solution...

Comment: @Dennis - yes, and that's what this answer does; as stated, it is limited to _one_ level of nesting, and going deeper would require _recursion_ - though representing that in a CSV could get impractical.

Comment: @mklement0 is your solution still valid also when one attribute returned from API is not single `[pscustomobject]` but an array of them? `if ($prop.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject])` will not trigger because it's not single `[pscustomobject]`. Will nested condition resolve it?

Comment: @soldous, no, if a property contains an array, this solution won't work. Note that since CSV column values cannot be arrays, you'd have to come up with a custom representation of an array that the consumer of the CSV needs to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any sample XML-data I can't verify that you can use this method to examine the object structure. But try this to get a grip of the structure you'd like to save...

```
Install-Module PowerShellCookbook

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $requestHeaders

[xml]$response | Show-Object
```

Edit: Show-Object is *really* old and I actually had some issues navigating an XML object. Also, when installing it there will be conflicts with these cmdlets already in place: Format-Hex,Send-File,Get-Clipboard,New-SelfSignedCertificate,Send-MailMessage,Set-Clipboard

I had to do Save-Module PowerShellCookbook instead and extract the single function Show-Object from the module file.

Edit 2: To explore the data structure, I concur with the discussion below that piping to Format-Custom is a more suitable option.

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` doesn't return _raw_ (XML or JSON) data - it automatically parses that data into a `[pscustomobject]` object graph, so your `[xml]` cast will fail.

Comment: Ah, but then there is no need to cast it. Just pipe it to Show-Object directly :)

Comment: Yes, but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: No, but the need is expressed in part of the comments; "what if I don't know the structure and I want to expand all [pscustomobject]s"

Comment: This need arises in the context of _programmatic processing_, so as to produce _CSV output_, not for interactive inspection by humans.

Comment: As an aside: if you want a _built in_ way of visualizing the structure of objects (for the human observer only), use [`Format-Custom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-custom)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware this isn't *the* answer. But a little knowledge about the actual structure will get you a long way when working at the solution...
And I really can't post the code in a comment.

Comment: Don't you need to know the structure to output before configuring `Format-Custom`?

Comment: Fair enough re providing an answer that _assists_ in finding a solution in general, but note that (a) we do have sample data now (as of this writing yet to be edited into the question) and (b) the very point of the question is to find a _programmatic_ solution that _doesn't have to know_  the specific structure.

Comment: Re `Format-Custom`: What makes you think you need to know the structure? Note that you may need to use `-Depth` to visualize the _full_ structure, in its full nesting depth.

Comment: It was actually an assumption. But now when I've tried `Format-Custom` on a sample XML-structure... It's awesome :) (But not so good on live objects :/ )